# page.php is not called when I load a Page

Tags: theme-development, customization

page.php is not called when I load a Page from my theme. However if I switch to the default wp theme and reload the page (not post), then only my header and footer are displayed.

I added some text to my themes page.php and index.php to output the filename of the page, but no filename is output.

The page I'm loafing is the contact us page, and it just uses the deafault template.

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Comment: Look at the page title (in the tab at the top of the page) - is it saying something like "Page not found"? You may be getting a 404 error - have you changed your permalink structure at all?